# Who is the "prodigal son" that shows up to dinner in Episode 1 of Unorthodox?

Tags: character, unorthodox

In episode 1 of Unorthodox, at 12:45 we see a man show up to dinner. He is greeted with "The prodigal son returns". The man takes a drink, eats some food, and then leaves. The subtitles refer to him as "Man 5" instead of giving his name.

Who is this man that shows up for dinner? How is he related to the family?

[image: Man 5 showing up to dinner]